# Experience with surfboard bike rack (or cart)

Tags: rack

I want to make (DYS) a rack or cart for carrying a surfboard on my bike. The idea would be to have space for only 1 board and being able to go as far as 150 km. So it should be as light as possible, comfortable and made of afordable materials (of course the combination will be located on an optimum non-perfect point). So, going through the internet I have seen a lot of different models, but I don't have any experience in relation to them. What configuration would you recommend me?  Depending on how the board is placed, I would be worry for being affected by the wind or making the bike and/or the cart inestable. Is the wind really a problem? I will use it in Scotland, so it could get windy.

Some examples: http://www.thesurfingblog.com/surfboard-bike-rack-the-many-styles/  (site dead 2015-12-02)

I like this one (if it works) http://www.bettersurfthansorry.com/prod-39-1-1386/.htm However, it seems way too expensive for what it is.

[image]

Comment: When I was growing up in Hawaii, this one kid Tamayo Perry (grew up to be a pro surfer) would ride from Hauula to the better waves up at Sunset with his board strapped to his bike. His rack looked home made but solid. I wish I knew more about it, I just remember his dedication to get to the bigs, and he got it!

Comment: My first thought is to turn it upside down, strap wheels on one end, then somehow attach the other end to the bike, similar to a "Bob" trailer.  Keeping it low would minimize wind problems.  (You may want a flashing light and/or 'bent flag on the back, though.)

Comment: If I understand your idea, the surfboard it self would be the structural element between the wheels and the bike (which actually it isn't a bad idea if you manage to attach it in a way that the strength is properly distributed...)

Comment: I see no reason why the surfboard couldn't be the structural element.  You could also have, eg, a piece of relatively lightweight pipe (eg, 3/4" EMT electrical conduit) connecting the two ends, just so you didn't have to rely on straps so much to hold things together, but the pipe would not carry any real weight.

Comment: And actually, rather than a BOB style trailer (which attaches low and requires a pivot arm of some sort to clear the wheel), maybe better would be to have a conventional rack on the back of the bike, then have one end of the board attach to the top rear of the rack like a "5th wheel trailer" on a pickup truck.  Basically, you strap an overgrown skateboard to one end of the board, hook the other end of the board to the top rear of the rack somehow, and go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Daniel R Hicks- go for a "Bob" trailer style- especially given the distances you're indicating you want to travel.  On the coast, there's always a breeze- and a surfboard turned broadside to the wind will turn your bike into a sail-a-bike and your 150km into what feels like 150,000km.

I'd hit some pawn shops or yard sales and look for one of those aluminum kid-trailers that clips to your rear frame.  You can disassemble the kid-carrying part and have a nice, low frame to strap not only your surfboard but other items you'll need for a trip that long as well.  The extra length of a trailer may not seem ideal to you at first, but I think after your first windy day to the beach, you'll appreciate the low-profile nature.

Here's the type of trailer I'm talking about: http://compare.ebay.com/like/230660800807?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar

Comment: I like your idea. I'm going to try a combination of all this. A bob trailer style where the board is the structural element. At some point I'll write a blog with the progress and I'll let you know how it goes, thanks!!! (I especially like the idea of re-cycling an old cart)

Comment: @JorgePM Any progress on this?  Would be very interested to see the final result.  I am facing the same problem right now and would be interested to see what you decided on.

Comment: Sadly no, but the summer is coming... I'll let you know if I manage to do some trials.